# How to print an unequal row length matrix in spiral form?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
{
  {4,5,6,7,8},
  {2,3,1,4},
  {1,2},
  {1,2,3,4,5}
  {5,6,7,8}
}
```

I want to print this in spiral way, so the output should be:
`4 5 6 7 8 4 2 5 8 7 6 5 1 1 1 3 1 4 3 2`

The code I currently have for spiral matrix is like this:

```java
void spiral(int a[][]) { 
    int i, k = 0, l = 0, m = a.length, n = a[0].length; 

    while (k < m && l < n) { 
        for (i = l; i < n; ++i) { 
            System.out.print(a[k][i] + " "); 
        } 
        k++; 

        for (i = k; i < m; ++i) { 
            System.out.print(a[i][n - 1] + " "); 
        } 
        n--; 

        if (k < m) { 
            for (i = n - 1; i >= l; --i) { 
                System.out.print(a[m - 1][i] + " "); 
            } 
            m--; 
        }

        if (l < n) { 
            for (i = m - 1; i >= k; --i) { 
            System.out.print(a[i][l] + " "); 
        } 
        l++; 
    } 
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to understand how to make it work for unequal array length rows. I would really appreciate any help and insight in this.

Comment: Your output has four occurrences of 1, while your input only has three?

Comment: Hm. You could "consume" the rows, that is remove elements from the arrays as you print them: Print the first row and remove all elements; print the last elements of all rows below that and remove them. Print the last row right to left; remove all elements. Print the first elements of the rows that still have elements bottom to top. Repeat. Stop when there's nothing more to print.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to it.  It can probably be more efficient, but it works:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws ScriptException {
    Integer [][] input = new Integer[][] {
                                    {4,5,6,7,8},
                                    {2,3,1,4},
                                    {1,2},
                                    {1,2,3,4,5},
                                    {5,6,7,8}
                                };

   List<List<Integer>> list = listify(input);
   processSpiral(list);
}

private static <T> void processSpiral(List<List<T>> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        printTop(list);
        list.removeIf(l -> l.isEmpty());
        printLast(list);
        list.removeIf(l -> l.isEmpty());
        printBottom(list);
        list.removeIf(l -> l.isEmpty());
        printFirst(list);
        list.removeIf(l -> l.isEmpty());
        processSpiral(list);
    }
}

private static <T> void printFirst(List<List<T>> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = list.size() -1; i >= 0; i --) {
            List<T> row = list.get(i);
            if (!row.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%s ", row.get(0).toString()));
                row.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static <T> void printBottom(List<List<T>> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        List<T> bottomRow = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        Collections.reverse(bottomRow);
        for (T i : bottomRow) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%s ", i.toString()));
        }
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
}
private static <T> void printLast(List<List<T>> list) {
    list.stream()
        .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
        .forEach(l -> {
            T i = l.get(l.size() - 1);
            System.out.print(String.format("%s ", i.toString()));
            l.remove(l.size() - 1);
        });
}
private static <T> void printTop(List<List<T>> list) {
    List<T> firstRow = list.get(0);
    list.remove(0);
    //print the first row
    for (T i : firstRow) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%s ", i.toString()));
    }
}

private static <T> List<List<T>> listify(T [][] input) {
    //convert to List of List for simplicity's sake
    List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T [] row : input) {
        //do not use Arrays.asList() as that creates an immutable List
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<>(row.length);
        for (T i : row) {
            l.add(i);
        }
        list.add(l);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.